# How Vuejs 2.6 to splice element of datarray as Observe?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, splice

I have data array like :

[image]
But I can not delete 1 element with splice like:

```
remove (index) {
 this.todos.splice(index, 1)
}
```

I found a way

```
 JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(todos))
```

and it is okey when I need to read data, but how to make splice ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use some like this ([manual](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)):

```
vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```